# DNN7 Navigation Within Same Compiled Module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am using the compiled module Visual Studio template.

I want to navigate between different ascx controls that I have added to the solution. 
When the user clicks a button I want to load a different ascx control and allow them to edit some data.

What is the best way to handle ascx to ascx control navigation within the same module?

Comment: When I try to register another control within the View.ascx page the other control will work, but the dropdownlist controls don't show correctly.  Any Ideas why a dropdownlist control in another ascx control won't render correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Navigating between DotNetNuke module controls using EditURL() or NavigateURL()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910578/2688) for details on the options available to you for navigating between controls in your module.

Comment: Yeah, there haven't been any changes for DNN 7.  DNN 6 added the idea of popups, so depending on the site settings, the module definition, and the chosen method of navigating, you may get a URL that's actually JavaScript to open the control in a popup.  But that's the only real change in `NavigateURL` in recent memory (and it affects `EditUrl` much more than `NavigateURL`, typically).

Comment: Do I need to register my new ascx controls in the *.*.dnn file?  I see that the Edit, View and Settings are in there.

Comment: If you want DNN to handle the navigation between the controls (i.e. via `EditUrl`), you'll need to register them.

Comment: The module is not going to be used by admins, it will be used by registered users only.  Can I use NavigateUrl to navigate between the 7 custom ascx controls and register all the controls as VIEW controls.

Comment: You can specify that all of the module controls are of the "view" type (but you'll need to give each their own control key).  To navigate between controls of a module, you'll use `EditUrl`, rather than `NavigateURL`, since it will pick up the context of the current module.  That said, using `EditUrl`-style navigation within a public-facing module isn't always the best experience, because it invokes "module isolation," meaning any other modules on the page are gone, and the site's edit skin is always used.  If you don't want either of those, you'll need to manage your own control loading.